# I can't connect tor browser. Please Help me

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, vpn

8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.400 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\zero\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.2" 
8/24/2017 9:43:56 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/24/2017 9:43:57 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/24/2017 9:45:28 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host ABCB4965F1FEE193602B50A365425105C889D3F8 at 192.34.63.137:443) 
8/24/2017 9:45:28 AM.400 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
8/24/2017 9:45:28 AM.400 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/24/2017 9:45:28 AM.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
8/24/2017 9:45:45 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/24/2017 9:45:45 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/24/2017 9:45:45 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/24/2017 9:45:45 AM.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: [ABCB4965F1FEE193602B50A365425105C889D3F8](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/ABCB4965F1FEE193602B50A365425105C889D3F8) is down. Have you explicitly configured it somewhere? What happens if you allow Tor to run for longer?